# Highchart Android How to implement drilldown in loop

Tags: highcharts

My problem is in the drilldown. I want to create a drilldown on loop but all drilldown series show in one serie, the result is when I click on column, all drilldowns series show in that char.

```
        ArrayList<Object> dataMinorAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> dataMajorAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> dataCriticalAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> dataDrilldownlAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> DrilldownlAlarms = new ArrayList<>();


        for (ResumenGraph data:resumenGraphs){
            HashMap<String, Object> minor = new HashMap<>();
            minor.put("name", data.getName());
            minor.put("y", data.getData().getMinor());
            minor.put("drilldown", data.getName());

            HashMap<String, Object> major = new HashMap<>();
            major.put("name", data.getName());
            major.put("y", data.getData().getMajor());
            major.put("drilldown", data.getName());

            HashMap<String, Object> critical = new HashMap<>();
            critical.put("name", data.getName());
            critical.put("y", data.getData().getCritical());
            critical.put("drilldown", data.getName());

            for (int i = 0; i < data.getDrilldown().size(); i++) {
                HIColumn series4 = new HIColumn();
                series4.setName(data.getName());
                series4.setId(data.getName());
                Object[] object2 = new Object[]{data.getDrilldown().get(i).getName(),data.getDrilldown().get(i).getData().getMajor()};
                dataDrilldownlAlarms.add(object2);

                DrilldownlAlarms.add(series4);

            }
            dataMinorAlarms.add(minor);
            dataMajorAlarms.add(major);
            dataCriticalAlarms.add(critical);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please remember "this not work" is not an actual description of your problem. Please read about [ask] in our [help] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use real `x` and `y` values from the `Point` class, there is not someting like `index` property.

You can find a similar example in the `highcharts-android` wrapper documentation.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#toc3

Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/blob/master/README.md